# meses desordenados en mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

mi pregunta es por que los meses en la base de datos salen desordenados y quisera saber el por que me salen asi les dejo el codigo sql

```
SELECT mes_traslado FROM formulario_precebo 
WHERE año_destete = 2017 
GROUP BY mes_traslado;
```

y el resultado que me da desde la base de datos es asi

```
1
10
11
12 
2
3
4
5
6
7 
8
9
```

se que hay una manera para ordenarlos pero quiero saber por que salen desordenados al hacer esta simple consulta

Comment: estan ordenados.. en forma de string.. seguramente es el tipo del dato del campo...

Comment: si es string el campo hay que castearlo a numero `order by cast(col as unsigned)` u `order by col+0`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11808592/1423096

Comment: @gbianchi el tipo del campo es varchar, entonces es por eso que salen asi cierto??

Comment: Totalmente.. para un string ese es un orden correcto.

Comment: @aloMalbarez Tu comentario debieras colocarlo como respuesta.

Comment: es que en realidad la "respuesta" es de gbianchi y la solución de jose-reynel , tal vez hacer un mashup para explicar el por qué pasa eso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Agrega la clausula ORDER BY de la siguiente manera. Saludos.**

```
SELECT mes_traslado*1 AS mes_traslado FROM formulario_precebo 
WHERE año_destete = 2017 
GROUP BY mes_traslado
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Ahora bien con el fin de dar contexto a la solución planteada al multiplicar por "1" la columna mes_traslado el sistema interpreta que es un entero y por tanto al realizar este tipo de "casteo" se genera utilidad para la clausula ORDER BY, el 1 en el ORDER BY se presenta con la finalidad que tome la primera columna que retorna la consulta y es reemplazable por el nombre de la columna. Sobre el uso de Alias tiene la finalidad de brindar un rotulo claro y no la operación en dicho rotulo.

Comment: Está mal, la cláusala es `ORDER BY nombre_columna ASC | DESC`, debería quedar `ORDER BY mes_traslado DESC`.

Comment: Buen día Kleith el "1" implica que va a tomar la primera posición que retorna la consulta, es equivalente a los campos que indicas... saludos

Comment: Podrías aclararselo, por si llega a poner una columna adelante y no le vuelva a funcionar.

Comment: Esto no soluciona ningun problema. Son strings, modificar la forma de orden no va a hacer que se ordenen como corresponde...

Comment: `mes_traslado*1` por si es un varchar

Comment: Alo tienes razón, es un casteo para evitar que lo interprete como string. muchas gx, ya complemento mi rpta. Saludos

Comment: @aloMalbarez tienes razon, esta base de datos yo no la cree, mi compañero lo creo por medio del framework `laravel` y la mayoria de los campos los creo como tipo `VARCHAR` por eso es que salen en ese orden

Comment: `mes_traslado*1 AS mes_traslado` para que no te cambie el nombre de la columna  ;)

Comment: Mas alla de que sea la respuesta aceptada, podes agregar porque haces lo que haces? la explicacion se pierde en los comentarios

Comment: vale Alo muchas gracias, ya complemento la rpta. Saludos.

Comment: vale gbianchi, voy a complementar dando contexto en la respuesta para que no se pierda en los comentarios cada parte de la misma. Saludos y muchas gracias por tu apreciación.

Answer (score 0):

Comparte **DESC formulario_precebo** para ver tu tabla, el **GROUP BY mes_traslado** va a omitir los meses duplicados si fuera el caso, el **ORDER BY mes_traslado ASC | DESC**  debería ordenar, si no lo hace debe ser porque el campo es varchar u otro tipo string.

Tu DESC ayudaría a saber si hay un id_table AutoIncremental, sí:

Tu **1** varchar le corresponde el AI (id_mes_traslado , por ejemplo) **1**

Tu **2** varchar le corresponde el AI **2**

**...**

De ser así podrías usar **ORDER BY id_mes_traslado ASC | DESC**

Comment: ya utilize `ORDER BY mes_traslado ASC | DESC` y me salio un resultado que no queria, pero vi en la base de datos y el campo esta como tipo `VARCHAR` por eso es que me salen los meses de esa manera

Comment: Tal vez te convenga hacer un alter a la tabla formulario_precebo para poner mes_traslado como TINYINT (un INT creo es demasiado si pensamos que el máximo valor será 12)